# Math does not render for tag excerpts in a couple places

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, tag-wikis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MathJax in tag excerpts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/mathjax-in-tag-excerpts)

Math does not render in a couple places related to tags.

Go to the "Tags" page on the main site and search for "lattice-orders". One tag will be found, and the LaTeX in its description will not be rendered.

Then hover over the tag name, and the LaTeX math in the popup window will also not be rendered.

Further examples of tags using math symbols are (at the moment):
[algebraic-curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-curves)
[cardinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardinals)
[fibonacci-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fibonacci-numbers)
[finite-fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-fields)
[integer-lattices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-lattices)
[irrational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrational-numbers)
[normed-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normed-spaces)
[ordinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordinals)
[periodic-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/periodic-functions)
[quadratic-forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratic-forms)
[rigid-transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rigid-transformation)
[roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roots)
[stirling-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stirling-numbers)
[transcendental-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transcendental-numbers)

Comment: LaTeX has never rendered in pop-ups (for technical reasons: MathJaX "post-processes" the page, so I am not sure how easy or advisable it is to force MathJaX to re-parse the entire page every time interactivity causes a javascript to update the page). So please avoid putting LaTeX in the short tag descriptions.

Comment: I've re-wrote the excerpt for (lattice-orders) to avoid the TeX expressions. Generally speaking: (a) simple mathematical descriptions can always be re-written in "plain words" (b) those that cannot represent ideas too complex to belong to a one-line blurb. Remember: tag excerpts are not just for experts to know what tags to use; it is also for non-experts to know which tags to *not* use.

Comment: Actually, the tag excerpts don't support any formatting at all, not just no MathJax.

Comment: @Willie Wong: You have broken my example :(. You might have waited until the bug was closed. Another example is the "complex-numbers" tag. I like to have one visible so people can see it with their own eyes.

Comment: Note that I did not put the LaTeX into the description, nor do I disagree that in general it can be avoided. I just filed the bug that the LaTeX is not rendered when it is included.

Comment: There is also [tag:integer-lattices] and, probably, many further examples can be found. Tags [tag:relations], [tag:integer-lattices] and [tag:lattice-orders] were my mistake - I did not realize that the excerpts do not support math and formatting. (When I viewed them in [tags tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) they seemed fine.) Next time I will know that I should avoid these.

Comment: BTW it seems that this was discussed here before: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/mathjax-in-tag-excerpts

Comment: @Carl: sorry to disappoint, but I like to have *no* examples of bugs -- I prefer a bug-free world.